# class App\Http\Controllers\Tarea not round

Tags: laravel

Me dice "" aunque la clase la tengo importada (creo que correctamente). ¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el error?
También probé no importarla pero al momento de invocarla escribirla como App\Tarea, pero aun así no funciona.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tarea;

    class formsController extends Controller
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            Tarea::create($request->all());
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La tienes mal ubicada, por qué las clases que funcionan como modelos viven en:

```
app/
```

Y en el namespace `App`

Entonces no hace sentido que a tu modelo lo invoques como si fuera un controlador cuando de hecho no lo es.

Entonces cuando requieres un modelo lo importas por medio de su namespace así:

```
use App\Modelo;
```

**Referencia**

- [Aquí puedes consultar más](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#inserts)

Comment: Ahora me dice "Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Tarea]." ¿Sabés cual puede ser el error?

Comment: Claro que sí, aunque eso no requiere edite y agregue más a está respuesta, en tu modelo Tarea debes tener una propiedad protegida llamada fillable y asignarle en un array el nombre de todas las columnas donde asignaras valores

Comment: Cierto, gracias. Perdón llevaba mucho sin usar Laravel